# autoValue executing both on client and server in collection2

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I have defined the `autoValue` option in my schema using `meteor-simple-schema` and `meteor-collection2`; however, since the schema definition runs on both client and server, all the code in my `autoValue` option is being run two times.

This is inefficient. Can I avoid one of the executions?

Comment: wrapping code in `Meteor.isServer` or `Meteor.isClient` will execute only once, Is it that simple or am I missing anything here?

Comment: Maybe it is, but if I use `console.log(Meteor.isServer)` inside my `autoValue` it outputs `false` twice. So it seems the `autoValue` option isn't executed at the server and that something else is causing it to run 2 times instead of 1. What could be wrong?

Comment: not sure, I haven't used this package much, better to check issues https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/491

Comment: I assuming you're doing an insert or an update that is triggering the autovalue?  Why not just run that code on the server?

Comment: How can I do that? Should I remove the code from my schema and instead trigger it manually or what?